video.js not starting or pausing on mobile browser with tap
I find it frustrating that video.js cant be started or paused or resumed with a tap on the video itself, instead we need to click on the controls. This isn't intuitive behaviour. I tried to solved this with userActions: true
var player1 = videojs('my-video1', {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: false,
  preload: 'auto',
  userActions: {
    click: true
  }
});

but no luck.
This behavious is also true for the video.js page, not just mine, so I wonder if any other frustrated developers have a fix for this?
I'm running the latest version 8.
